# POSTMAN Visualizer adding auto-increment into a response table

Tags: html, json, postman

I've created a postman test which visualises JSON response from an endpoint as a table.
The thing is that the response often has many result but these are not numbered, visualised response looks like this:
[visualised response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qflMZ.png)

rowID is hardcoded and the same for each row. I would like to have it somehow auto-incremented starting from 1.

My shortened code looks like this:

```
let template = 
`
 <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <style>
    tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2;}
    th, td {text-align: center;}
    th, td {font-size: 14px;}
    </style>
 
        <tr bgcolor="#0887C4"; style="color:white;">
            <th>Row</th>
            <th>City [16-17]</th>
            <th>Postal Code</th>    
        </tr>

        {{#each response.results}}
            <tr>
                <td>rowID</td>
                <td>{{path.is.here}}</td>
                <td>{{path.is.here}}</td>
               </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>
`

pm.visualizer.set(template, {response: JSON.parse(responseBody)})
```

Is there any simple way to do this? I'm completely new to Postman and I'm not quite sure where to start or what I can use.

EDIT
Example json looks like this:

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "errorMessage": "string",
  "ok": true,
  "results": [
    {
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 0,
        "longitude": 0
      },
      "address": {
        "address1": "string",
        "address2": "string",
        "address3": "string",
        "address4": "string",
        "buildingNumber": "string",
        "country": "string",
        
        },
        "location": {
          "id": 0,
          "name": "string"
        },
        "postalCode": "string",
        "street": {
          "id": 0,
          "name": "string"
        },
        "location2": "string"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: add a example json

Comment: What @PDHide said, an example would help provide you with a working solution. I also think that there's a built in helper that will display the index `{{@index}}` if you add that as the rowId. It's zero indexed though.

Comment: @DannyDainton the {{@index}} works fine, although it stars from 0 as you've mentioned, anyway I'm satisfied with this solution because it's quick and easy.

Comment: I've also edited the post and added example json.